# Using indexing to automate task to pull yelp businesses

Tags: pandas, python-requests

I think what I'm looking for is more of a programming question than how to use Yelp GraphQL or anything like that. Maybe this question is better suited for stackexchange? Just let me know, and I will post it there.

In the following script I'm pulling the yelp businesses within each census block within a radius from the center of the block as a way to workaround yelps limit on businesses. However, there is a larger Yelp limit where you only have so many credits per day. Obviously, I'd want to start the script where it left off, which is easy if I'm doing this manually (in the output of the csv, every time the code moves to a new census block, in the "categories" variable, the categories will == "categories", so I can filter these, and get the length, and then this tells me how many blocks have been looped through). However, I'm trying to automate the task and am unsure how to actually code this into the program, such that the program begins with census block 0, and then once the daily limit is reached, it will then taken on the new value of len(yelp_block) in the code).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
import constants

block_centroids = gpd.read_file("block_centroids.geojson")
bc = block_centroids

bcx = bc['x'].tolist()
bcy = bc['y'].tolist()

print(len(bcx))

bcx = bcx[0:]
bcy = bcy[0:]

print(len(bcx))

service_key = constants.yelp_api_key

#define headers
header = {'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(service_key),
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#build request framework
transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql', headers = header, use_json = True) #params = PARAMETERS

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

business_list = []

for i in range(len(bcx)):
    params = {
      "location": "san diego",
      "limit": 50,
      "offset": 0,
        "radius": 200,
      "longitude": bcx[i],
      "latitude": bcy[i]
    }

    query_bus = gql("""
      query sd_businesses($location: String, $limit: Int, $offset: Int, $radius: Float, $longitude: Float, $latitude: Float){
        search(location: $location, limit: $limit, offset: $offset, radius:$radius, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude) {
          total
          business {
            name
            coordinates {
              latitude
              longitude  
            }
            categories {
            title
          }
          }
        }
      }
    """)

# Execute the query on the transport
    result = client.execute(query_bus, variable_values=params)
    #pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result['search']['business']
    #df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
    df = pd.json_normalize(result['search']['business'])
    df.to_csv('yelp_businesses.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=True) #make sure file is yelp_businesses for final run

#saving all businesses to yelp_businesses.csv
```

yelp_businesses.csv will look like this:
[image]

[image]